# Why the view is null outside onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I declare a view variable in the class and assign its value in OnCreateView using `findviewbyid` as usual, and I use an interface to interact between this fragment and another one, when the other fragment interacts with this fragment using a method called **"ask"** in which the local variable is invoked, I find that the variable is `null` Here is the variable

```
private TextInputLayout questionLayout;
```

Here I assign its value

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article_, container, false);
    Button ask = v.findViewById(R.id.ask);
    questionLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.QuestionInputLayoutArticle);
    if(questionLayout == null){
        Log.d("ORDERARTICLE","QUESTION");
    }
    Log.d("ORDERORDER","CreateView");
    return v;
}
```

Here is the method

```
  @Override
public boolean ask() {
    Log.d("ORDERORDER","ASK");
    if(questionLayout == null){
        Log.d("ORDERARTICLE","QUESTION");
    }
    if(questionLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }else {
        FirebaseFirestore Fs = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Map<String, String> QuestionMap = new HashMap<>();
        QuestionMap.put("Head", questionLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
        QuestionMap.put("Type", "Article");
        Fs.collection("Questions").document().set(QuestionMap);
        return true;
    }

}
```

You can note that I am logging to make sure that the value is assigned before invoking the variable and it's assigned before invoking indeed

Comment: How do you create the other fragment?

Comment: Using new.. :/ i know this is wrong for the arguments

Comment: Is it visible on the screen in two fragments? When the other fragment appears on the screen, does the previous fragment detach?

Comment: Yes, but i create new instance every time i invoke the method